# How to close Matplotlib plot during Python thread operation?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have problem with python thread. after opening a matplot in thread,plt.close doesn't work and it hangs. does anyone know how to close matplot in thread.when thread function finishes, matplot closes but I intend to close plot during thread operation

Run matplot in python thread and close it during thread implementation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My main problem is how to close plot during thread execution